# trying to do a simple horizontal alignment in center

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying 4 horizontal divs in a box, but they are not aligning. Lets say I want to add 4, 5 ,6 or 7 little boxes horizontally even, how would I do that? This is my HTML and css code below. The first 3 aligns good, but when I add the others, it just puts them in other spots

and this is my link in case. Its the one all the way at the bottom

http://codepen.io/willc86/pen/hpFLe

```
#box2{
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#left1{
  border: 1px solid green; float: left; margin-left: 30px;
}


#right1{
 border: 1px solid red; float: right; margin-right: 30px;
}

#middle1{
 border: 1px solid tan;  margin: auto; width: 50px;

}

#middlerightbox{
 border: 1px solid blue; margin: auto; width: 50px;

}




      <div id="box2">
         <div id="margin">
             <div id="left1">
               hello
             </div>

             <div id="right1">
               hello
             </div>

             <div id="middle1">
               hello
             </div>

           <div id="middlerightbox">
               hello
             </div>

         <div class="clear"> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried floating them all to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
#box2 {
border: 3px solid green;
margin: 40px;
height: 20px;   // necessary!
text-align: center;
}

#left1 {
border: 1px solid green; float: left;
}


#right1 {
border: 1px solid red; float: left;
}

#middle1 {
border: 1px solid tan;  float: left; margin: auto;
}

#middlerightbox {
border: 1px solid blue; float: left; margin: auto;
}

<div id="box2">
<div id="margin">
<div id="left1">hello</div>
<div id="right1">hello</div>
<div id="middle1">hello</div>

<div id="middlerightbox">hello</div>

<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

Ask for more help if necessary!